# sed returns the following error sed: -e expression #1, char 101: unknown option to `s'

Tags: bash, sed

I'm writing a script to replace a label `<p>` with a path in some text files (`*.prop`). However , when I run it I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 101: unknown option to `s'
```

My code is the following:

```
sed -i --  "s/<q>$(echo $destpath | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' -e 's/\//\\\//g' -e 's/&/\\\&/g')/\ResultsTesting/\/g" *.prop
```

and if I print the echo of my code:

```
sed -i -- \
s/<q>\/home-students\/rmorales\/testAPK\/air.air.air.com.tabc.gsn-2014_5_11-dex2jar\/ResultsTesting\//g \
myFile.prop
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

here's how i would do it:

```
printf %s\\n "$destpath" |
sed -e 's|[]\$/^.*[]|\\&|g' \
    -e 's|.*|s/<q>&/ResultsTesting\\//|' |
sed -i -- -f- myfile.prop
```

*(part of)* your problem is you're *(apparently)* quoting for the wrong side. for the the Left-Hand-Side of the `s///`ubstitution statement you need to escape the following characters:

```
$^.*\[] delimiter
```

the first two need only be escaped in certain positions, but it doesn't hurt to escape them otherwise and so you might as well escape them all. the delimiter in your command is `/` - as is customary.

for the Right-Hand-Side you need to escape:

```
\& delimiter newline
```

which appears to be what you're trying to do *(though the quotes need some work)*. while there really isn't anyway to escape a newline in the LHS *(besides replacing it entirely with the substitutive escape string `\n`)*, they can be escaped on the RHS. but you're inserting your escaped text into the LHS.

in the example above i use two `sed`s - as do you - but rather than an in-place command-substitution i feed the commands in over a left-to-right pipeline *(as is usually my preference)* and source the resulting `sed` script on stdin with the `-f-` switch.

Comment: This is great.  Very nicely done.  You're right that the double-quotes weren't relevant; I deleted my inaccurate answer.  What was really the issue with the OP's version was: trying to use `/`s as delimiters to the `s` command while escaping `/`s...which were then being dropped in the middle of another `sed` command which was also using `/`s as delimiters to its `s` command.  Hence the leaning toothpick syndrome which you neatly and totally sidestepped with your use of `-f-`.

Comment: @Wildcard - yeah, personally i almost never do things that would require me to `s/\///` more than once or twice. but i also very seldom opt for any other delimiter - excepting `|`. its just style, but `s#thing#otherthing#` confuses the hell out of me most of the time. and so i will generally either opt for `[/]` for fixed strings, or, for variable values, i will escape them thoroughly and feed them in otherwise.

Comment: One question: Why the `--`?  In my tests the command works without that just fine.  ...and another question, actually; where is `-f-` documented?

Comment: @Wildcard - i would expect `-f` is documented in your `man sed` docs. you can find the [spec here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html). the `-` is specified to mean: *the standard input shall be used ... if a file operand is '-' and the implementation treats the '-' as meaning standard input.* most systems do treat `-` to mean stdin, though Solaris doesn't, i think, even if it can be referred to like `/dev/fd/0` on those systems. the `--` was used in the question and so it is used here. the truth is i lied - i wouldnt do it like that. i never use `-i`.

Comment: I have a question, when I run it, I get the following error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `-'
`

Comment: @RodrigoMoralesAlvarado - leave off the `--`, I guess.

Comment: @mikeserv If I leave it off, the error disapears, but it doesn't modify the prop file